# Creating feature in mac app to override the users security setting

Tags: macos, cocoa, security, app-store, preferences

I'm a newbie at mac osx development. I would like to know if there's any way to override the mac desktop security settings to allow an application - which is not registered in the Mac App Store, to be installed?

The setting should come from the app that I'm trying to install. That means, whenever I install the app to any mac computer, regardless of its security settings as the following,

Allow applications downloaded from:

- Mac App Store
- Mac App Store and identified developers
- Anywhere

The app should set the settings to **Anywhere**, allowing it to be installed.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This sound very malicious. There is no real value add to what you are intending to do and makes me question your intentions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is not possible. The existence of that setting is intended to protect users from malicious executables. If there were a way for any arbitrary executable to override that setting, what protection would it offer? Malicious executables would simply change the setting to "Anywhere" like you suggest, bypassing the security features of Mac OS X.

Comment: You're absolutely right, Greg. That made sense. Thanks for your response.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I was able to open the file by navigating to it in the wider and Command+O

Answer (score 71):

1. Launch System Preferences from the Apple menu.
2. Choose “Security & Privacy” and then click the “General” tab, followed by clicking the lock icon in the corner to unlock the settings.
3. Look for “Allow applications downloaded from:” and choose “Anywhere”.
4. Accept the security warning and allow.

Note that you should be careful and aware that now the job of protecting the system from malicious apps belongs to you instead of the OS.

Comment: Wrong.  The question is clearly asking for something that the app can do, not something that the user can do.

Comment: I agree with @JWWalker...I'm not asking how to make restrictions on app installation. CodeCurmudgeon..please take a little time to read the whole thing first. I appreciate your effort though...

Answer (score 23):

Right click the (app) icon and click 'open' in contextual menu - no need to disable the OS security.

Answer (score 3):

You need to sign your application using a Mac Developer certificate, which you can obtain from Apple. That will mark your app as built by an "identified developer" and it will launch just fine without changing any settings.

Answer (score 1):

Control Click the app icon to override this security feature. This is a one off, you don't have to change your settings, you can do it per-app.

Answer (score 1):

There is one other way...

All you have to do to do it manually is to open up Terminal, cd into the .app application, cd into the Contents folder, then cd into the MacOS folder, then type ./YourAppNameHere and execute by typing Enter.